# How to find a specific inverse function.

Tags: functions, inverse

I am developing a new probability distribution. The probability density function is as follows:

$$f(x) \, = \, 
\frac{x^{r+1}}{(r+1)^{x}}\frac{ln(r+1)^{r+2}}{
(r+1)!}$$ with $0<x$ and $r = 1, \, 2, \, 3,\, ... \,$ . The distribution function is as follows:

$$F(x) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{r+1} (1/i!)(r+1)^{-x} x^i ln((r+1))^i$$

Define $G(x) = 1 - F(x)$:

$$G(x) =  \sum_{i=0}^{r+1} (1/i!)(r+1)^{-x} x^i ln((r+1))^i$$

I am searching for the inverse of $G(x)$. Does a solution exist?

Answer (score 1):

For $r=1$,

$$G(x)= 2^{-x}\left(1+ x \ln2+ \frac12(x \ln2)^2\right)$$

is of the form $2^{-x}P(x)$ where $P$ is a polynomial. Such functions are not invertible analytically. The same holds for $r>1$.

Comment: Yves Daoust Thank you for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

May I start remarking that it looks for me like some Poisson distribution:
$$G(x) =  \sum_{i=0}^{r+1} (1/i!)(r+1)^{-x} x^i ln((r+1))^i$$

Now, to start set $a:= ln(r+1) >0 $ then
$$G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{r+1} e^{-ax} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!}= e^{-ax} \sum_{k=0}^{r+1} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!} $$
This shows (which is needed later), that $G$ can be expressed as a product of two power series and thus can be written as a power series itself.

Now let us get the derivative of $G$ and find out if it is monotonic:
$$G'(x) = -a e^{-ax} \sum_{k=0}^{r+1} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!} + e^{-ax} \sum_{k=1}^{r+1} a\frac{(ax)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} = \\
-a e^{-ax} \sum_{k=0}^{r+1} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!} + ae^{-ax} \sum_{k=0}^{r} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!} =\\
=-a e^{-ax}\frac{(ax)^{r+1}}{(r+1)!}
$$
Then if $r>0$ we have $a =ln(r+1) > 0$ and hence the  the last line gets negative for positive $x>0$ . Under this condition for $r$ and $x$ then $G'$ is negative on $\mathbb{R}^+$, thus it is monotonic (decreasing) and therefore invertable.

Furthermore as has been noted previously that $G$ can be expressed as a power series, we could apply the [Lagrange–Bürmann formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)  to find the coefficients of the inverse function's power series coefficients.

**Addendum**: Please note that
$$G(x) =  e^{-ax} \sum_{k=0}^{r+1} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!} = \frac{\Gamma(r+2,ax)}{ \Gamma(r+2)}=Q(r+2,ax)$$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables))where $\Gamma(.,..)$ is the *incomplete Gamma function*, $\Gamma(.)$ is the well known *Gamma function*, and $Q$ is the *regulized Gamma function*. All these functions are available by many math libraries, and their inverses are so as well. Just in case you need explicit expressions take a [look here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized3/introductions/Gammas/05/).

Comment: Maksim, you concluded that
$$G(x) =  e^{-ax} \sum_{k=0}^{r+1} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!} $$
The derivative of this function is
$$ G'(x) = \frac{ a^{2} e^{-ax} (ax)^{r} x}{(r+1)!} $$
This is not the same as the derivative you gave:

$$G'(x) = (1-a)e^{-ax}\sum_{k=0}^{r} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!}-a \frac{(ax)^{r+1}}{(r+1)!} $$
Did I make an error?

Comment: You didn't - but I did. My apologies. I corrected the calculation, and I think we now are in line. :-)

Comment: I intend to write an article about the probability distribution above and I need the inverse of the function $G$ to be able to simulate $x$ values. How many coefficients of the power series of the inverse function do you think I will need?

Comment: Pls. have a look at my addendum in the answer.

Comment: On [look here][1] I read at the end:
The inverse of the regularized incomplete gamma function   $Q^{-1}(a,z)$ satisfies the following ordinary nonlinear second-order differential equation:
$$w(z) w(z)'' - w(z)'^{2} (w(z)-a+1) = 0$$  with  $w(z) = Q^{-1}(a,z)$.
You conluded that 
$$G(x) = \frac{\Gamma(r+2,ax)}{ \Gamma(r+2)}=Q(r+2,a x)$$
My question is now: how to proceed further. I am aware that $a$ in the first equation is not the same as $a$ in the second equation.
  [1]: http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized3/introductions/Gammas/05/

Comment: Maybe a look into ["EFFICIENT AND ACCURATE ALGORITHMS FOR THE
COMPUTATION AND INVERSION OF THE INCOMPLETE
GAMMA FUNCTION RATIOS"][1] might help?


  [1]: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.1754.pdf

Comment: this is used in boost : "Computation of the incomplete gamma function ratios and their inverse" Armido R. DiDonato , Alfred H. Morris

Comment: Maksim Thanks a lot for the information. I an going to look into it as soon as possble. You are of great help till now. Thanks again.